# Convert UTC to local time in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, timezone, activesupport

I'm having trouble converting a UTC `Time` or `TimeWithZone` to local time in Rails 3.

Say `moment` is some `Time` variable in UTC (e.g. `moment = Time.now.utc`). How do I convert `moment` to my time zone, taking care of DST (i.e. using EST/EDT)?

More precisely, I'd like to printout "Monday March 14, 9 AM" if the time correspond to this morning 9 AM EDT and "Monday March 7, 9 AM" if the time was 9 AM EST last monday.

Hopefully there's another way?

**Edit**: [I first thought](https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994-ruby-on-rails/tickets/6574) that "EDT" should be a recognized timezone, but "EDT" is not an actual timezone, more like the state of a timezone. For instance it would not make any sense to ask for `Time.utc(2011,1,1).in_time_zone("EDT")`. It is a bit confusing, as "EST" **is** an actual timezone, used in a few places that do not use Daylight savings time and are (UTC-5) yearlong.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

Rails has its own names. See them with:

```
rake time:zones:us
```

You can also run `rake time:zones:all` for all time zones.
To see more zone-related rake tasks: `rake -D time`

So, to convert to EST, catering for DST automatically:

```
Time.now.in_time_zone("Eastern Time (US & Canada)")
```

Comment: How could you automatically use the time zone for the user accessing the web app?

Comment: The only way I found was with Javascript and then passing it back to the server.  `(new Date()).getTimeZoneOffset()`.  But it's fairly inconsistent, so this guy seems to have written his own: http://www.onlineaspect.com/2007/06/08/auto-detect-a-time-zone-with-javascript/

Comment: automatically add the time zone to all ActiveRecord datetimes -- config.time_zone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)' -- in config/application.rb

Comment: Update: owner of linked JS solution points to newer solution: http://pellepim.bitbucket.org/jstz/

Comment: @dmonopoly you can set the timezone in the application config `config.time_zone = 'Wellington'` and then use Time.current (which is equivalent to time.now but used the Timezone that you have set)

Answer (score 133):

`Time#localtime` will give you the time in the current time zone of the machine running the code:

```
> moment = Time.now.utc
  => 2011-03-14 15:15:58 UTC 
> moment.localtime
  => 2011-03-14 08:15:58 -0700
```

Update: If you want to conver to specific time zones rather than your own timezone, you're on the right track. However, instead of worrying about EST vs EDT, just pass in the general Eastern Time zone -- it will know based on the day whether it is EDT or EST:

```
> Time.now.utc.in_time_zone("Eastern Time (US & Canada)")
  => Mon, 14 Mar 2011 11:21:05 EDT -04:00 
> (Time.now.utc + 10.months).in_time_zone("Eastern Time (US & Canada)")
  => Sat, 14 Jan 2012 10:21:18 EST -05:00
```

Comment: That's a start. How can I set the current time zone (since I'm not even sure where the app will be hosted, the server could be in a different timezone then what should be used).

Comment: The "localtime" method is cool, but the time zone of the machine running the code isn't as helpful as the time zone of the user accessing the web app. (As mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003491/rails-3-user-timezones/6105487#6105487) How could you get the time zone for the user accessing the web app?

Comment: @daze I imagine you could set up an option for your users to choose their timezones, and then use the `in_time_zone` method with their timezone.

Comment: `Time.now.localtime` works on a normal irb session but when I try to run it on a machine which is in UTC timezone, it doesnt work.

Comment: if machine in UTC timezone, I guess user expects UTC, no?

Answer (score 18):

It is easy to configure it using your system local zone,
Just in  your application.rb add this

```
config.time_zone = Time.now.zone
```

Then, rails should show you timestamps in your localtime or you can use something like this instruction to get the localtime

```
Post.created_at.localtime
```

Answer (score 15):

There is actually a nice Gem called `local_time` by basecamp to do all of that on client side only, I believe:

https://github.com/basecamp/local_time

Comment: This works the best. We know the time stored already, the way to show it in the format to user is best done on the client side in my opinion and this does it.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know why but in my case it doesn't work the way suggested earlier.
But it works like this:

```
Time.now.change(offset: "-3000")
```

Of course you need to change `offset` value to yours.

Answer (score 1):

If you're actually doing it just because you want to get the user's timezone then all you have to do is change your timezone in you `config/applications.rb`.

Like this:

**Rails, by default, will save your time record in UTC even if you specify the current timezone.**

```
config.time_zone = "Singapore"
```

So this is all you have to do and you're good to go.