# What is the reference for Time.localtime

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When using the `localtime` method on a UTC `Time` object, is the time returned the local time as specified in the app configuration or the local time of the user's location?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert UTC to local time in Rails 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5300493/convert-utc-to-local-time-in-rails-3)

Comment: Rails has custom classes and methods for dealing with timezones, e.g. [`TimeWithZone`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.0/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone.html) and various [extensions](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#extensions-to-time). Within a Rails app, you should use those methods instead of the built-in ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`localtime` will give you the time in the current time zone of the machine running the code.

Apidock(localtime): for [ruby](https://apidock.com/ruby/Time/localtime), [ruby on rails](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone/localtime)

Answer (score 0):

.localtime in your app will show your app's time. To display localtime to different users you will need to add some Javascript.
This answer might help you.

[How to display the time in user's timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5267170/how-to-display-the-time-in-users-timezone)